# How to populate input with jquery on-click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to populate an input field on click with jquery, currently am able to populate a normal html field but not an input field, the reason i want to achieve this is to enable submissions because currently the data populated on html field is not being submitted, I beleive that populating this data in an input field will enable possible submissions.
I am currently using the following code to achieve this:

```
function populatethefield() {
  document.getElementById("populatethisfield").innerHTML = "data to be populated to the field";
}
```

The field html

```
< p id="populatethisfield"><p>
```

This works, but i want to populate an input field, rather than a paragraph field.

Comment: where is input field and onclick method ?

Comment: `$("#id").val(value)` - you did tag this jquery but only had verbose javascript?

Answer (score 0):

When trying to change the value of an input field, you have to access the value property because inputs do not have an `innerHTML`, but a `value` instead. See code below for a demonstration:

```
<input type="text" id="target" placeholder="test" />

<script>
document.getElementById('target').value = "Value Updated.";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for

```js
$('.populate').click(function(e){
    var data = 'Some Content'
    $("#populatethisfield").html('<input value="'+data+'">')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="populatethisfield"></p>

<button class="populate">Populate Input</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a pure jquery solution use the `val()` method for input fields.

```js
$('.populate').on('click', function() {
    $('#target').val("data to be populated to the field");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="target" placeholder="test" />
<button class="populate">Populate Input</button>
```

Comment: `$('#target').val() = "data to be populated to the field";` wont work the way you wrote

Comment: @DeepakA, i rushed that. i was looking for a way to put in a runnable code snippet. I'm on my mobile device. it's corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <script>
          function changeValue(value){
          document.getElementById("input").value= "Hello World";
          }
          
       </script>
       <body>
          <input type="button" onclick="changeValue(2)" value="Button">
           <input type="text" id="input" value="">
       </body>
    </html>
```